# How to put buttons in activity header?

Tags: android, android-titlebar

I'm trying to design a dialog, which looks similarly to the system one:

[image]

Are these buttons planted on the application title bar? Or are they simply placed in the UI?

Comment: Both of ways are correct

Comment: You can build UI how you want to implement and show on screen

Comment: http://www.edumobile.org/android/action-bar-search-view/

Comment: use **ToolBar/ActionBar** to use as activity header

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a ToolBar to do this. This is an example with *icon-based buttons*, but you can easily modify it into Text Buttons.

### ToolBar Tutorial

1 - Add library compability

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

2 - Create a file name `color.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="ColorPrimary">#FF5722</color>
    <color name="ColorPrimaryDark">#E64A19</color>
</resources>
```

3 - Modify your `style.xml`

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

4 - Create a file name `toolbar.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

5 - Include the ToolBar into your `main_activity.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        ></include>

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/TextDimTop"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

6 - Put it inside your `MainActivity` class

```
package com.example.hp1.materialtoolbar;

import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity { /* When using Appcombat support library
                                                         you need to extend Main Activity to
                                                         ActionBarActivity.
                                                      */


    private Toolbar toolbar;                              // Declaring the Toolbar Object


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar); // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);                   // Setting toolbar as the ActionBar with setSupportActionBar() call

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

7 - And finally, add your "Button Items" to the `menu_main.xml`

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        ></item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_user"
        android:orderInCategory="300"
        android:title="User"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_user"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"></item>

</menu>
```

Comment: Thanks for the extensive example. I managed to implement custom toolbar from your example, however I failed to add two buttons of equal size like on the screenshot. Could you please assist in this matter as well?